# Why the passed in parameter type is by default the value of generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I saw a generic function like this:

```
const myFun = <T>(p: keyof T extends 'foo' ? never: T)=> {
    console.log(`...`);
 }

myFun('foo') // good
myFun({foo: 1}); // bad: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

I have one question:

When calling `myFun`, I only pass in either string or object, I don't explicitly tell typescript the value of generic type `T` like `myFun<string>(...)`, it seems the function is already considering the passed in parameter type as the value for `T` & starts evaluating the condition `keyof T extends 'foo'`, I wonder why is that? Is that the default behavior of typescript that the argument type is by default the value of generic `T`?

Comment: It's called type inference. If you don't want it then you can write `myFun<SomeType>(...)`. But if you do want to call the function without specifying the type parameter explicitly, how else would you want the type parameter to be inferred, other than from the argument?

Comment: @kaya3 my confusion is not type inference but how it is inferred. I mean there is an evaluation `keyof T extends 'foo'`,  I thought typescript would only know/infer the type after this evaluation is done but it actually already use the passed-in parameter type as the value for `T` before the evaluation.  That's my concern & would like to understand why behaves like that. Whether it is ts default behaviour that immediately infer value of `T` even there is an type evaluation waiting there.

Comment: How could `keyof T extends 'foo' ? ... : ...` be evaluated before `T` is inferred?

Comment: That's true. I agree.  So, can we conclude that's the default behaviour in general that `T` is inferred based on the passed in parameter type in the first place always in ts? Or is only in this case? Could you please elaborate it? or probably depending on the place where T is used?

Comment: I'm not sure what the precise rules are when type parameters are used in conditional types, but in general Typescript will try to infer type parameters from the context at the call-site, which includes the arguments and the contextually-expected return type (in some cases). That said, in this kind of example, `T` is not always just the type of the argument, it is inferred in some way *based on* the type of the argument, and in your example it is exactly the type of the argument probably because the conditional type says the argument must either have type `never` or type `T`.

Comment: Here are a few examples, including two where the type parameter `T` isn't simply the argument's type, it is inferred by inverting what `Bar<T>` does, which is sometimes possible. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJwDwBUB8UC8UDeAjRALihQF8AocgMwFcA7AY2AEsB7OqYCAZ2AEZUaABSIA5sRRQIADy50AJt1xVWrYnRoBbPBASkoAfhJR1EAG66AlMTOtm83BVqMW7Tj2AAmQSITjjMnKKyqrqWjp6hlB05romJNZQtvaO1PRMbBxcvADMPmISUrIQCko4KmrR4br6RvDI6PExFgiJyQ44TumuWR4ALPl+hYElweWhVdo1Uc1xxPWCbXYdFOQA9GvG2OOVGlN65Nn8QjvEnjmklgDclBtbuAQIYfsUR54nj8R9npc365uSbYVZ4RV4eHIfIghSrnUi-W4ArCTCKHfqQp5Qb7woA)

Comment: That said, since I don't know what the actual rules that govern this are, I will leave it to the more knowledgeable people to write a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks @kaya3! I checked your playground samples, and I have posted a question about it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71283832/two-generic-functions-both-passed-in-the-same-parameter-but-evaluated-different