# Two generic functions, both passed in the same parameter but evaluated differently, why

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have the following code of generic functions:

```
type Bar<T> = {bar: T}

function test1<T>(arg: T extends {foo: number} ? T : never): void {}
function test3<T>(arg: T extends {foo: number} ? Bar<T> : never): void {}
```

When I call them:

```
test1({foo: 23}); // Good!
test3({foo: 23}); // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

I get confused, I mean shouldn't both `test1(...)` and `test3(...)` evaluating type condition of `arg: T extends {foo: number}` to be true? I mean they have exactly the same parameters passed into the functions & they have the same evaluation condition for types.

In other words, Why `test3({foo:23})` falls into the `never` value for type instead of `Bar<T>`? I also expect the `test3({foo:23})` fail but with an error message that says expecting `{bar: number}`,  why error messages instead complains the `never` side?

Comment: Well, the second function has an argument which has to either be of type `Bar<T>` for some `T`, or `never`. You are calling it with an argument that is not of type `Bar<T>` for any `T`, so therefore its type has to be `never`. The reason the error message doesn't say "expected `{bar: ...}` is because (if you don't think too hard about it, which the compiler doesn't), this conditional type doesn't say the argument has to have type `Bar<T>`, it says the argument has to have type *either* `Bar<T>` or `never`.

Comment: But the condition in the 1st place to evaluate is neither `Bar<T>` nor `never` but `arg: T extends {foo: number}`. The passed in parameter should pass the 1st place check isn't it? Only after that the type is either `Bar<T>` or `never`. So my question is why the 1st place check should pass which in reality isn't? I get more confused now how typescript treat the order for type checking in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get confused, I mean shouldn't both `test1(...)` and `test3(...)` evaluating type condition of arg: T extends {foo: number} to be true?

In `test3`, you've said the argument would be `Bar<T>` when `T extends {foo: number}`. So it would expect `{bar: {foo: number}}` since `Bar<T>` is `{bar: T}`. Since what you're passing it can't match `Bar<T>`, `never` is used.

If you pass it what you've said it should receive, it works just fine:

```typescript
test3({bar: {foo: 23}}); // Good!
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJwDwBUB8UC8UDeAjRALihQF8AocgMwFcA7AY2AEsB7OqYCAZ2AEZUaABSIA5sRRQIADy50AJt1xVWrYnRoBbPBASkoAfhJR1EAG66AlMTOtm83BVqMW7Tj2ABmQSITjjMnKKyqrqWjp6hrCIgiZQdOZWNnYOOBTkXLx8QjgqalAATJ6klgDcUBWVVVAA9DVQAOKq8gCEGR6eOQQIxLmhhcUl5ZV1jc0tQA)

Comment: You hit the point! I would expect typescript only do what you said if the function signature is this: `function test3<T>(arg: T extends {foo: number} ? Bar<T> ? Bar<T>  : never): void {}` , so, your answer basically is saying typescript doesn't need me to explicitly tell like `Bar<T> ? Bar<T>  : never`...oh...complex ts, too many alternatives to make code readable for me... I personally feel this brings more confusions when reading code  :('

Comment: @user842225 - I didn't follow that bit of code there, but basically you've said `T` should extend `{foo: number}` and then only used `T` in `Bar<T>`, so it's going to try to match the argument to `Bar<T>` and use `never` if it can't. Remember, it's `T` that TypeScript is trying to match, so in this case that means it would need to be wrapped in `Bar`.

Comment: I mean if you look at the function signature, there is no explict `Bar<T> ? Bar<T>  : never` but the `never` is for the condition `arg: T extends {foo: number}` when reading the code.  I would expect typescript does what you explained (which makes sense now to me) if signature contains that : `function test3<T>(arg: T extends {foo: number} ? Bar<T> ? Bar<T>  : never): void {}`, (my point here is the `Bar<T> ? Bar<T>  : never`) , hope you get what I am trying to say.

Comment: Btw, this post is originated from comments discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71283328/why-the-passed-in-parameter-type-is-by-default-the-value-of-generic-type  , I wonder would you be able to also elaborate my question there? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user842225 `Bar<T> ? Bar<T> : never` doesn't mean anything, you need a condition of some kind prior to the `?`, like `x extends Bar<T> ? Bar<T> : never`. You have no `x` you can provide there. But the way to look at it (I think; I'm not a TypeScript expert) is: TypeScript is trying to match `T`, and the argument has to be `Bar<T>` to do that; it isn't, so TypeScript uses `never`.

Comment: @user842225 - I have nothing to add there over what kaya3 has said. (They know TS a lot better than I do!).